# why should i move this http call to an external service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am early on in my angularjs development.

I have created a single page app. A couple of the areas call controllers that have code like below embedded in them.

**snippet from the route::**

```
.when('/searchDrug/:searchStr', {
    templateUrl: SNIPsArray['searchresultsSNIP'],
    controller: 'searchDrugCtrl'
})
```

**snippet from the controller::**

```
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {         
  $http.get(url).success(function(data) {

    if ( data.drugmaster.length == 1 ){
       $location.path('/fetchDrug/'+data.drugmaster[0].drug_Id);
       return;
    }
    $scope.druglist = data.drugmaster;
  });
}
```

**Question:**
looking on the angularjs site and reading some articles on best practices, it is suggested to move $http from the controller to a service. I am looking for some help on what the advantage is of adding another level and another file for this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maintainability**

As your application grows, you will find that there will be more and more need of encapsulating your business logic somewhere. In angular you do this using services.

**Encapsulation**

Not only do services allow you to reuse code, but also to introduce good principles like abstraction and encapsulation.

**Richer domain**

What's also important to note is that perhaps you want to introduce some additional modelling and functionality above what you get back from the service. With a service, you can do stuff like do the http call, then wrap the results in a function with some methods on it. This results in a much richer domain model and readable code.

For example, here the search function returns a promise with some domain logic on it to massage the data coming back from the service:

```
function ($scope, $routeParams, $search) {  
  $search($scope.drug)
    .then(function(result){
        $scope.drugList = result.getDrugList({include: ['title', 'description']});
    });
}
```

**Testing**

It's obviously much better to write tests for a controller that depends on a service and tests for a service on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Because of code reuse, maintainability and testability. Testing resources is a separate process than testing whole controller.